# DevDemon Channel Videos searches return "The vimeo request failed!"

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

Trying to add vimeo videos in a channel entry and all attempts return "The vimeo request failed!"

EE 2.11.9 and CV 3.2.0

What I have tried:
 - search with or without kewords
 - search with or without author
 - enter vimeo's Video URL

Don't see anything in the logs.

Comment: V 4.0.2 is out and I seem to recall a recent upgrade because of Vimeo API update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm with Vector, the people behind DevDemon)

This problem is due to Vimeo changing their API which requires some changes to Channel Video's integration.

We [updated Channel Videos for EE3 for this API Change back in February](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/version-history/channel-videos/) and as of August 2nd 2017 have updated the EE2 version as well. [Download and install Channel Videos 3.3 for a fix](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos).

Comment: Hey Matt, 

Thanks for the positive feedback and background. Customer service FTW!  This plugin is on a legacy site that will be terminated at the end of the year so EE3 isn't an option for us.

Looking forward to the fix and thankful for the other user who hired you to do it, I need to buy that person a beer!

Comment: @BryanHickey We've now released the fix! v3.3: http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos

Answer (score 0):

How can we fix this error if using EE 2.11?  Now all of us want or have upgraded to EE3.